# Add multiple rows of the same id for a contact list

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am making a chatting program in Java and I need to make a contact list .
I want a user ID to have multiple conversation ID-s

The USERS table has 5 columns including the ID (Unique)

And I want to insert into the USER_CONVERSATIONS table like this

```
user_id  |  conversation_id
   1     |   3
   1     |   4
   4     |   1
```

etc..  (user_id is the foreign key of the ID in the USERS table)

so when i search for the user with id 1 it will give me the array of the conversation ids and i can put it in a JList.

I'm a beginner in databases so i could use some help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for help creating a conversation table, how to insert records to that table with a reference, or something else?

Comment: Your USER_CONVERSATIONS table should have its own primary key conversation_id which is unique.  And your user_id in this table should be a foreign key to the USERS table.


SELECT
   user_id,
   conversation_id,
   message
FROM USER_CONVERSATIONS
INNER JOIN USERS ON USERS.user_id = USER_CONVERSATIONS.user_id;

Comment: I want to insert the data like the example but it doesn't let you put the same ID-s

Comment: Anoml Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your USER_CONVERSATIONS table should have its own primary key conversation_id which is unique.  And your user_id in this table should be a foreign key to the USERS table.

NOT NULL = cannot be empty

IDENTITY(seed,increment) = Auto-increment (seed = start value, increment = add amount)

```
CREATE TABLE USER_CONVERSATIONS
(
  conversation_id  INT   NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,
  [user_id]        INT,
  message          VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO USER_CONVERSATIONS
(
  user_id,
  message
)
SELECT
   user_id,
   'Hello World!'
FROM USERS;
```